# Display result after validating for loop in Matlab

Tags: matlab

In the following code, I check to see if the first letter is in the dictionary of words and if the length of the word matches. If it does, return the word. Otherwise, return an error statement.

```
words = {'apple', 'banana', 'bee', 'salad', 'corn', 'elephant', 'pterodactyl'};

user_letter_input = input('Please enter the first letter of a word: ', 's');
user_num_input = input('Please enter how long you would like the word to be: ');

for i = words
    if ((i{1}(1) == user_letter_input) && (length(i{1}) == user_num_input))
        result = i;
    else
        result = 0;
    end
end

if (result == 0)
    disp('There are no matching words');
else
    disp(['Your new word is: ' result]);
end
```

The comparison returns `i` being `'apple'` if I type `a` for the first input and `5` for the second input - as it should.

However, at the end when I try to see `if (result == 0)`, it does not display the new word, even though `result` is not 0.

Could someone help me fix this please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are overwriting `result` each time through your for loop. The only time that `result` will be 0 after the loop, is if the last word in `words` matches your criteria.

I would recommend storing the matching words in a separate cell array, or have a boolean array to indicate which words match. In my opinion, using a boolean is better as it takes less memory and doesn't duplicate data.

```
words = {'apple', 'banana', 'bee', 'salad', 'corn', 'elephant', 'pterodactyl'};

user_letter_input = input('Please enter the first letter of a word: ', 's');
user_num_input = input('Please enter how long you would like the word to be: ');

isMatch = false(size(words));

for k = 1:numel(words)
    word = words{k};
    isMatch(k) = word(1) == lower(user_letter_input) && ...
                 numel(word) == user_num_input;
end

if ~any(isMatch)
    disp('There are no matching words');
else
    disp(['Your matching words are:', sprintf(' %s', words{isMatch})]);
end
```

Also, as a side note don't use the cell array in the for loop like that. That leads to a lot of confusion. Also [avoid using `i` as a loop variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14790740/using-i-and-j-as-variables-in-matlab).

Comment: This would also handle multiple matches.

Answer (score 1):

You're overwriting `result` each time the word in your dictionary doesn't match. The only time this will work is if the last word matches. You need to change both your initialization of `result` and your loop:

```
result = 0;   %// assume that no words match
for i = words
   if (....
      result = 1;   %// we found a match... record it
   end
   %// no else! If we get no match, result will already be 0
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a flag to detect whether a match was found:

```
breakflag = 0
for i = words
    if ((i{1}(1) == user_letter_input) && (length(i{1}) == user_num_input))
        breakflag = 1;
        break;
    end
end
if (breakflag == 0)
    disp('There are no matching words');
else
    disp(['Your new word is: ' i]);
end
```